# Access /data folder files in android

Tags: java, android, file, directory

I have rooted my device and I have install busybox. Now I want to access /data folder files through my application. My application have super user permissions but still I am not able to access file .
Can any one know how to do this (with or without busybox)?

Please help me.

Code:

```
if ((new File("/data/bin/su")).exists())
    SU_COMMAND = "/data/bin/su";
else
    SU_COMMAND = "su";

String command1 = "busybox mount /sdcard \n";
String command2 = "busybox mount /system \n";
String command = "busybox cp /data/data/com.my.test.app/databases/ /mnt/sdcard/testapp/ \n";
Process process = (new ProcessBuilder(as)).start();
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
java.io.OutputStream outputstream = process.getOutputStream();
outputstream.write(command1.getBytes());
outputstream.flush();
```

Comment: What is your programming related problem?

Comment: @Mudassir : I have tryed some of method but I cannot access the file like if I use command for copy the file to sdcard then I got permission denied exception but it I use only ls command in data folder it give me list of all the folder easily with out any error

Comment: if((new File("/data/bin/su")).exists())
                 SU_COMMAND = "/data/bin/su";
             else
                 SU_COMMAND = "su";   String command1="busybox mount /sdcard  \n";
   String command2="busybox mount /system  \n";     String command="busybox cp /data/data/com.my.test.app/databases/ /mnt/sdcard/testapp/  \n";   Process process = (new ProcessBuilder(as)).start();
   
   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); java.io.OutputStream outputstream = process.getOutputStream();
   outputstream.write(command1.getBytes());
   outputstream.flush();

Comment: Sure it is executing, but what does it returns, true or false?

Comment: @Mudassir :I don't know what it return but if I use ls command in place of cp it provide my access to data folder that means I application is getting super user permission and the supperuser application is showing dialogbox for confirm superuser access for application

Comment: @jjNford It is not my question

Comment: you are never actually running su in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this one:

```
 private boolean run(boolean runAsRoot, String cmd) {

    String shell = runAsRoot ? "su" : "sh";

    int exitCode = 255;
    Process p;
    try {

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shell);
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

        os.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
        os.flush();

        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        exitCode = p.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.e("Exception", e1.toString());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
    }
    return (exitCode != 255);
}    

public boolean copyFile() {
    return run(true, "busybox cp /data/data/com.my.test.app/databases/ /mnt/sdcard/testapp/");
}
```