# Access to /data/data/com.whatsapp

Tags: android, root

Hy, while building an android application for 2.3.3 I got the following error:

I tried to access the files:

```
private static final String src_msg = "/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db";
private static final String src_wa = "/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/wa.db";
```

I do su before:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

I tried to copy the files to sdcard via cp command -> no success
I tried to check if the files exists via `new File(src_msg).exists()` -> no success

I use the following permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

what else is missing here? the popup to allow root comes up and has been accepted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325469/access-data-folder-files-in-android  check this question

Answer (score 1):

Try that: (Thanks to ramdroid )

```
private boolean run(boolean runAsRoot, String cmd) {

String shell = runAsRoot ? "su" : "sh";

int exitCode = 255;
Process p;
try {

    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shell);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
    os.flush();

    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();

    exitCode = p.waitFor();

} catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.e("Exception", e1.toString());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
}
return (exitCode != 255);
```

}

```
public boolean copyFile() {
return run(true, "busybox cp /data/FILE TO COPY space DRECTORY TO COPY");
}
```

Change only YOUR_DIRECTORY and DIRECTORY TO COPYto the needed ones.

Comment: you just copy-pasted the answer, and your cp command is infact wrong

Comment: You do know you have to copy it to a directory your own right? Milos doesn't know which directory you want so he left that part out.

Comment: @vikki, yes, that's why I said thankd to ramdroid.I dont know which directory he would like to use, this part should be customized.

Comment: @tolgap doesn't make the command right does it? when answering a question you don't know everything about OP's situation, you leave template code, but it should at least be valid code.

Comment: Nope! see how ramdroid did it, first is the file you want to copy `space` and then the dir in which to copy it.... which is why you shouldn't have copied the answer in the 1st place.

Comment: This was the YOUR DIRECTORY but ok, I reedited my answer, happy now ? :)